# selectedItemPropertyChanged cancel Event

Tags: java, javafx

i have following problem:

```
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldV, newV) -> {
            if (!selectionChanged(newV)) {
                lististView.getSelectionModel().select(oldV);
            }

    });
```

selectionChanged(newV) just pop a Message Box with "You wanna select new value?" and return the result as a boolean value. When i click on cancel it returns false, so that the condition is true. But because of .select(oldV); it would be result in a loop. How can i cancel or rollback a selection in javafx listview?

Answer (score 2):

Create a boolean flag and don't ask the user if it is not set. You need to wrap the change back to the original value (if the user vetoes the change) in a `Platform.runLater(...)` to avoid issues with conflicts in the selection model's `selectedItems` list (basically you cannot change a list while another list change is being processed).

```
private boolean checkSelectionChange = true ;

// ...

listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldV, newV) -> {

    if (checkSelectionChange) {
        checkSelectionChange = false ;
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (!selectionChanged(newV)) {
                lististView.getSelectionModel().select(oldV);
            }
            checkSelectionChange = true ;
        });
    }
});
```

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewSelectionUserVeto extends Application {

    private boolean checkSelectionChange = true ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().addAll("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (checkSelectionChange) {
                checkSelectionChange = false ;
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    if (! verifySelectionChange(newValue)) {
                        listView.getSelectionModel().select(oldValue);
                    }
                    checkSelectionChange = true ;
                });
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(listView);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private boolean verifySelectionChange(String newValue) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setContentText("Change selection to "+newValue);
        return alert.showAndWait().filter(ButtonType.OK::equals).isPresent();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sduniii Are you using the updated answer (with `Platform.runLater(...)`)? Is this happening with the SSCCE?

Comment: ok my fault. i added a a.showAndWait().isPresent() && a.showAndWait().get() != ButtonType.OK what called the box twice. thx